# How can I implement 'RenderPartial' method for 'ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat'?

Tags: servicestack

I added ServiceStack.Razor configuration to the ServiceStack sample project RestIntro, added a Views folder containing _Layout.cshtml and Customers.cshtml, when i browse the app

```
http://webserver:5000/Customers.cshtml
```

i get the error msg below:

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'RenderPartial' in type 'ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Razor, Version=3.9.42.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

What didnt i do right?

Comment: Does browsing to http://webserver:5000/Views/Customers work?

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see your `Customers.cshtml` markup to know for sure, but based on the exception try replacing your `RenderPartial` method calls with just `Partial`.

[ServiceStack's HtmlHelper](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Html/HtmlHelper.cs#L106-L124) doesn't include a `RenderPartial` implementation. Although looking at the source code, it's implementation of `Partial` is actually equivelent to MVC's `RenderPartial` (i.e. it doesnt return the rendered partial as a string, but writes it direct to the output buffer, even though the method sig returns a string, its always null). Not sure if this is by design or an issue, I found this question looking for an answer to exactly that!